# Catalyst + mod_cgi

Tags: perl, catalyst

I recently developed a [catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/) application which I would now like to deploy.
My host ([OVH](http://www.ovh.com)) allows perl applications via mod_cgi.
Unfortunately, I'm used to running my catalyst apps on mod_perl.
I have no experience with mod_cgi whatsoever, and I can't seem to find
good documentation on how I should get my catalyst app running on mod_cgi.

Any chance that some of you guys could give me a hand?
Has anyone of you ever run a catalyst app on OVH's services?

Thanks,
ldx

Comment: just mod_cgi, not mod_fastcgi?

Comment: There's nothing difficult about it, but be prepared for page hits that take a couple seconds for *very* simple apps, up to perhaps 10 seconds for complex apps. Catalyst is *not* intended to be run non-persistently.

Comment: if so, you'd best be looking for a different host.  though google shows a number of questions about mod_fastcgi installation/configuration on OVH forums - are you sure?

Answer (score 3):

[`catalyst.pl`](http://p3rl.org/catalyst) creates a CGI program.

```
Foo-Bar> cd ..
> catalyst.pl -scripts Foo::Bar
> ls Foo-Bar/scripts/
```

For Catalyst 5.8, the code of `Foo-Bar/scripts/foo_bar_cgi.pl` excluding POD looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Catalyst::ScriptRunner;
Catalyst::ScriptRunner->run('Foo::Bar', 'CGI');

1;
```

Answer (score 2):

[Catalyst::Engine::CGI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Catalyst-Runtime/lib/Catalyst/Engine/CGI.pm) is the base module you have to look at. If your Catalyst code is backend-agnostic you should be able to just drop that in your base app, create a CGI file through which your whole application runs, and it will all work.

The CGI environment though is going to be very much slower than fastcgi or even mod_perl.

Comment: Thanks, that is already helpful. Any pointers on how to create such a CGI file?